# How to return constant value from string in php?

Tags: php

Here is constants:

```
define('Qc',        1);
define('D1',        1);
define('D2',        1);
define('S1D1',      1);
define('E1D1',      1);
define('E1D2',      1);
define('An',        1);
define('D3',        1);
```

Formula comes from database:

```
$formula = "Qc + D1 + D2 + S1D1 + E1D1 + E1D2 + An + D3";
```

Expected result: 8

Comment: $formula is string which is comes from admin settings (database). This formula may changed. for example: "100 * (Qc + D1) /2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
$formula = "Qc + D1 + D2 + S1D1 + E1D1 + E1D2 + An + D3";
$formulaBreak = explode('+',$formula);
$val = 0;
foreach ($formulaBreak as $bk) {
   if (defined($bk)) {
      $val += (int)constant( trim($bk) );
   }
}
echo $val;
?>
```

PHPFiddle http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/mau-z2w

**Important:**

The key is you can get the value for constant by a string with

```
constant( 'STRING' );
```

As defined by Jobaer Shuman in the comment the formula can be in any format, you can parse the formula take out the `variables` and then get the value of the constant out of string with the help of above code

Comment: I would add a if(defined($bk)) in the foreach too, just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks. It's works for me. But have any solution if change logical operator? For example formula changed to $formula = "100 *((Qc + D1 + D2) - E1D1)

Comment: you're welcome, for parsing the formula you might need to use `regex`, I would suggest you to create another question in that case asking for how to parse a string for variables/formula showing at least couple of formulas . I'm not very good with `regex`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get this code example. Do you get the constant values from the database or just a formula which tells you which constant to add?

Anyways the code example won't give you 8 because you give it to $formula as string.

Try removing the " from there. If that doesn't work try casting the constants to an int like this.

```
$formula = (int) CONST1 + (int) CONST2
```

Comment: Constant value is predefined. Formula comes from database as string.